# store intermediary results in pipe

Tags: r, magrittr

I want to store intermediary results in a pipe, but somehow this is not compatible with the `%>%` pipe operator:

```
if(!require(pacman)) install.packages('pacman')
pacman::p_load(dplyr, magrittr)

# generate test data
a <- 1:5 

# this works perfectly
b <- a %>% exp %T>%
  { a.mean <<- mean(sqrt(.)) } %T>%
  { a.sd <<- sd(sqrt(.)) } %>% 
  round(2) 

b

a.mean
a.sd

all.equal(a.mean, mean(sqrt(exp(a))))
all.equal(a.sd, sd(sqrt(exp(a))))    

# this not so much
b2 <- a %>% exp %T>%
  { a.mean2 <<- . %>% sqrt %>% mean } %T>%
  { a.sd2 <<- . %>% sqrt %>% sd } %>%
  round(2)

b2

a.mean2 # 'functional sequence
a.sd2   # 'functional sequence
```

Comment: Here, you are doing some calculations repeatedly.  You could change it to `f1 <- lift(compose)(exp, sqrt);a %>% f1 %>% {list(mean(.), sd(.))}` instead of creating some objects

Comment: There is a mistake in the code `fl <- list(exp, sqrt);a %>% lift(compose)(f1)(.) %>% {list(mean(.), sd(.))}`

Comment: I want to create these objects. I know that it might not be particularly useful in this example. The question is why the pipe operator does not work in creating objects that way.

Comment: I understand that.  But, I am showing a simpler way to create the objects without doing repeated calcuation

Comment: the objects that I want to create can't be simplified like that because the pipe contains non-standard functions

Comment: anyway, my point is that you don't need `<<` inside it, can be created as a `list` and then use `list2env`

Comment: My question is about the pipe operator. I will rephrase the obviously misleading question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe chains starting with `. %>%` will build functional sequences, the content of `.` is not evaluated.

If you use `(.) %>%` you'll get the behavior you expected.

```r
library(magrittr)
a <- 1:5 

b2 <- a %>% exp %T>%
{ a.mean2 <<- (.) %>% sqrt %>% mean } %T>%
{ a.sd2 <<- (.) %>% sqrt %>% sd } %>%
  round(2)

b2
#> [1]   2.72   7.39  20.09  54.60 148.41

a.mean2 
#> [1] 5.684048
a.sd2
#> [1] 4.232675
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>